# Multiple wildcards in one SSL (generating request)

Tags: ssl, iis, wildcard

I wish to have an SSL certificate covering legacy domains (DNS will point all domains to the single web server, our exchange will also handle incoming email from multiple domains).  I have found a "multiple wildcard in SAN" SSL provider.

The SSL provider states:

> By default, this product will secure 2 wildcard domains (for example:
>   *.yourdomain.com and *.domain.com) and must have a non-wildcard domain (for example: yourdomain.com) listed as the base domain, or Common
>   Name
>   (I will need to "add on another wildcard domain" to the purchase obviously as I need 3x wildcard domains)

As for generating the REQ for the provider (Using IIS 7.5), would I generate a normal SAN request with wildcards in the SAN?

For example, I need to cover *.mydomain1.com  *.otherdomain1.org and *.yetanotherdomain.net

so I'm guessing I need a "proper" common name - **mydomain1.com** then add wildcards as SANs:

1. *.mydomain1.com
2. *.otherdomain1.org
3. *.yetanotherdomain.net

My question; is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

First you should request Multi-Domain Wildcard SSL certificate for any of your main domain using asterisk (*). i.e. `*.mydomain1.com`

Afterwards, you should add additional domains `*.otherdomain1.org`  and `*.yetanotherdomain.net` to same SSL certificate. To cover all these domains in single certificate, you will require to purchase one more SAN (as you have mentioned about default pack is of two domains). I would suggest to check [this post](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/difference-between-san-ssl-vs-wildcard-ssl-certificate), if you have any confusions regarding the best suitable certificate upon your requirement.

If your main domains and sub-domains exist on same server, you will need to install certificate only once. But any of your domain(s)/sub-domain(s) is on another server, you will require to reissue certificate and install it on different server. Kindly note, some providers offer free re-issuance while few charge for it, so confirm first.

It seems like, your approach is correct, you should purchase Multi-domain Wildcard certificate to protect sub-domains from different sites (*.mydomain1.com, *.otherdomain1.org, *.yetanotherdomain.net, etc.).